# What is the "correct" way to change hostname in CentOS 6.5? (And difference between /etc/hosts and /etc/sysconfig/network scripts)

Tags: java, linux, networking, centos6, hostname

**Some background:**

I am testing an LTTng (Linux Trace Tool) Control view plugin that I wrote in Java. Yes, I know there is a control view that comes with LTTng when installed in Eclipse, but I wanted to play.

My plugin is pretty much start and stop buttons that calls the lttng terminal commands to start and stop traces. The GUI prints out the status of the trace (enabled, disabled, paused, running), the hostname of the tracing node, and the current trace name (if running). This post concerns getting the hostname of the tracing machine (let's focus on the local machine for now).

**My hostname understanding:**

From what I can tell after some Googling, there are three places where hostname shows up in CentOS (I'm sure there are more, but these are the important ones):

- /etc/hosts

  > 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
  >
  > ::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
- /etc/sysconfig/network

  > NETWORKING=yes
  >
  > HOSTNAME=localhost
- `hostname` command in terminal

  - returns "localhost"

First I ran `hostname newHostName` in the terminal. Running `hostname` with no arguments "newHostName" is printed back. Once I reboot, however, the hostname is set back to whatever is in the /etc/sysconfig/network file ("localhost" by default). So the next go around, I changed /etc/sysconfig/network and rebooted. Now "newHostName" is correct in the /etc/sysconfig/network file and when I run the hostname command from the terminal "newHostName" is returned. Yay!

**Problem:**

When just changing the /etc/sysconfig/network file, my plugin throws an `UnknownHostException` on the line `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();`

So I changed the /etc/hosts file to the following:

> 127.0.0.1   **newHostName** localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
>
> ::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

Now everything works!...but I'm not sure why...

**My question is two parts:**

1. What is the "correct" way to change a hostname in CentOS? (I am on CentOS 6.5)
2. What is the difference between the /etc/hosts and /etc/sysconfig/network files?

Answer (score 0):

you set hostname and save it to kernel parameter.

```
hostname MyHost
sysctl kernel.hostname=MyHost
```

or you can set this config on Linux run level also.